# How can I copy text by simply highlighting it (jammy)?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, clipboard, copy, copy-and-paste

One of the great features of Linux for me was always that I can copy text to the clipboard by simply highlighting it. This worked well for me under Debian and then Ubuntu for a long time.

Under Ubuntu focal it mostly would work well, but no longer for libreoffice and firefox. (It was unreliable and often would copy only part of the text highlighted and sometimes nothing.)

Moving to jammy it seems to work well for firefox (as far as I have tested it), not at all for libreoffice and not at all for qutebrowser (the browser I would like to use). It continues to work well for emacs, mc and the terminal.

I use diodon and I have enabled in configuration: "Use clipboard (Ctrl+C)", "Use primary selection", "Keep clipboard content", "Automatically paste selected item". (And not: "Add images to clipboard history", "Synchronize clipboards".) But "Use primary selection" should be the relevant one. (I also tried out to enable "Synchronize clipboards", but this didn't help.)

I tried two other clipboard applications: Qlipper does copy even less and doesn't provide access to relevant configuration options. Gpaste offers more options than Diodon. But if I enable "Synchronize clipboard with primary selection" every intermediate step is put into the clipboard. (Example: Highlighting "Then" I would have "T", "Th", "The", and "Then" in the clipboard. Clearly not what I want.)

Question: Is there any way under Ubuntu jammy to have the clipboard behave for all applications in a consistent manner and copy whatever I highlight, but only after I finished highlighting it?

Comment: ISTR an earlier question which suggested that snap was the issue.

Comment: I removed snap totally, no change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem partially by moving to a different clipboard manager: copyq. Copying by highlighting now also works for qutebrowser and falkon, another QtWebEngine based browser. (It still doesn't work for libreoffice.)